# semi-freezing ripe avocado for easier handling

Tags: freezing

I've got a sack of ripe avocados that are going to be used in
vietnamese salad rolls, sliced into long pieces. The avocados
are getting bit too soft to cut, and I'm considering putting 
them in the freezer for 1-2 hours to harden them up so they'll
be easier to peel and cut. 
Am I asking for trouble putting my avocados in the freezer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid freezing them as it will change the texture. A lot of people say they don't notice, but I notice right away. I can tell if food has been frozen in the first bite.

I just halve them, take out the pit and then slice them lengthwise in the skin.
Then with a spoon carefully scoop out the slices.
Works like a charm, no matter how soft.

Answer (score 2):

Freezing will not successfully firm up the avocados and make them any easier to cut.  Also, it makes them brown faster and they will be squishy inside the salad rolls, which you don't want.

I suggest making guacamole with the avocados you have, and buying some new firmer ones for the salad rolls.